# Drop down list width fit selected item text

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way in javascript/jquery or css to make html `<select>/@Html.DropDownList` auto width so it fits currently selected item, I tried with `diplay:inline-block` and `width:auto` but width always seems to fit largest item on list?

Comment: Im just curious, why downvote?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My answer is similar to D3mon-1stVFW's, but instead uses a hidden drop-down to set the width on dynamically.  As long as you use the same styling for your hidden and "real" one, it should account for different font sizes, decoration, etc.  Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- this is our hidden "template" drop-down that we'll
     use to determine the size of our "real" one -->
<select id="template" style="display:none;">
  <option id="templateOption"></option>
</select>
<!-- this is our "real" template that will be re-sized -->
<select id="sel">
  <option>Short</option>
  <option>Really, Really, Really Long</option>
</select>​
```

And the Javascript:

```
function setSelectWidth() {
  var sel = $('#sel');
  $('#templateOption').text( sel.val() );
  // for some reason, a small fudge factor is needed
  // so that the text doesn't become clipped
  sel.width( $('#template').width() * 1.03 );
}

$(document).ready( function() {
  setSelectWidth();

  $('#sel').change( function() {
    setSelectWidth();
  } );​    
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kn9DF/1/

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, but I'm little suprised that it requires so much hacking..

Comment: In my case it worked when I set "width:auto" style to template element

Answer (score 3):

Variation on @Ethan Brown's answer, with the `.val()` corrected to `.text()` and a dynamically-created `select` so your page isn't polluted:

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
  <option>Short</option>
  <option>Really, Really, Really Long</option>
</select>​
```

JS:

```
function setSelectWidth(selector) {
    var sel = $(selector);
    var tempSel = $("<select style='display:none'>")
        .append($("<option>").text(sel.find("option:selected").text()));
    tempSel.appendTo($("body"));

    sel.width(tempSel.width());

    tempSel.remove();
}

$(function() {
    setSelectWidth("#sel");

    $("#sel").on("change", function() {
        setSelectWidth($(this));
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kn9DF/242/

Tested on Chrome 39, FF 36, IE 11.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a generic jQuery function you can drop into any page. It immediately resizes all selectors and ensures they will be resized when they are changed.

```js
function setSelectWidth() {
    var $yardstick = $('<select><option>' + $(this).val() + '</option></select>')
    $yardstick.css({display: 'none'}).appendTo('body');
    var fudge = 1.03; // need a little more to avoid clipping for some reason    
    $(this).width( fudge * $yardstick.width() );
    $yardstick.remove();
}

function initSelectors() {
  $('select').each(function() {
    setSelectWidth.apply(this);
  }).one('change', function() {
    setSelectWidth.apply(this);
  });
}

initSelectors();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- examples -->
<select id="example-1">
    <option>Short</option>
    <option>Really, Really, Really Long</option>
</select>

<select id="example-2">
    <option>Tiny</option>
    <option>A bit bigger</option>
    <option>Huuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuge</option>    
</select>
```

The script is forked from Ethan and Ian's answers. The initSelectors function does need to be re-called if you add a selector, but it uses jQuery `one` so it can be safely called multiple times if previous selectors remain on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this sample I wrote.  Use the same when you create the list, just get the default selected and set it in the span and get its width.

```
<script>
    function newSelected(ele){
       document.getElementById('jsize').innerHTML = ele.value;
       document.getElementById('selectList').style.width = ($(jsize).width()+30)+'px';
    }

</script>

<span id="jsize" style="display:none"></span><br />

<select id="selectList" onchange="newSelected(this);">
    <option>small item</option>
    <option>a really big long item</option>
</select>
```

​
see http://jsfiddle.net/39ffp/2/  it can be tweaked

Comment: It's still the same. I'll go to js fiddle to test it maybe something is wrong with my code.

Comment: Well still doesn't work at least not in FF 11, Ethan got it right from your answer