# All properties on nativeElement.style are empty

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am trying to create a select that will resize to the width of the selected item.

Here's the implementation in jQuery/Javascript: [Drop down list width fit selected item text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10307262/5157959)

The problem I'm having is that the styles are always empty. If I try to set the mainSelectElement to hiddenSelectElement, it almost disappears. The reason is that nativeElement.style.width is blank. I logged the style property to the console, and every property is blank. We also have global styles applied to select, and those are not appearing either.

Does anyone know why my styles are blank? Does this have something to do with the shadow DOM? And best of all, any solutions?

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

const SELECT_RESIZE_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useClass: forwardRef(() => SamSelectResizableComponent),
  multi: true
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sam-select-resizable',
  template: `
    <select #mainSelectElement [ngModel]="selected" (ngModelChange)="updateSelected($event)">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </select>

    <select #hiddenSelectElement>
      <option >{{selected}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
  providers: [
    SELECT_RESIZE_VALUE_ACCESSOR
  ]
})
export class SamSelectResizableComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @ViewChild('hiddenSelectElement') hiddenSelectElement: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('mainSelectElement') mainSelectElement: ElementRef; 

  public selected: any;

  private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = (_: any) => {};
  private onTouchedCallback: () => void = () => {};

  get value(): any {
    return this.selected;
  }

  set value(val: any) {
    if (val !== this.selected) {
      this.selected = val;
      this.onChangeCallback(this.selected);
    }
  }

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

  updateSelected(event) {
    this.selected = event;
    const hiddenWidth = this.hiddenSelectElement.nativeElement.style.width;
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainSelectElement.nativeElement, 'width', hiddenWidth);
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value !== this.selected) {
      this.selected = value;
      this.onChangeCallback(this.selected);
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be taking width from `nativeElement` directly, instead of taking it from `style`

```
const hiddenWidth = this.hiddenSelectElement.nativeElement.clientWidth; //.width
```

Comment: This solved the problem, but it doesn't answer the question about why the styles are empty. In the browser, all my styles are being applied, so I assume this is some shadow dom issue.

Comment: this doesn't address the question at all. Why are the styles blank?

Answer (score 6):

Here is some nice way to fetch the styles once they are applied. Initially all the style properties are empty for any HTML element.

**window.getComputedStyle()** may resolve your issue.

```
// fetch styles for an element
style = window.getComputedStyle(hiddenSelectElement.nativeElement, null);

// fetch the property values for any style attribute
console.log(style.getPropertyValue("width"));
```

For pseudo elements like `::before` and `::after`

```
// fetch styles for an element
style = window.getComputedStyle(hiddenSelectElement.nativeElement, ':before');

// fetch the property values for any style attribute
console.log(style.getPropertyValue("width"));
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle